# Public function from another script isn't called in Unity2D

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make an attack mechanic for my 2D game. It would work as follows: if the player was standing in front of the enemy and pressed space the enemy would die. To do that I wrote this in the player script:

```
    void Attack()
{
        Collider2D[] hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(AttackArea.position, AttackRange, EnemyLayers);
        foreach (Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies)
        {
            enemy.GetComponent<Enemy_1>().Death();
            
        }
  }
```

And this in the enemy script:

```
    public void Death()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

It worked flawlessly but I wanted to make another type of enemy to the game so I added this for the second enemy in the player attack script (I have mention that "GunBoi" is the name of the second enemy script and that I named the second function "Dead()" instead of "Death()" since I thought it wouldn't work if they had the same name)

```
Collider2D[] hitEnemies2 = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(AttackArea.position, AttackRange, EnemyLayers);
        foreach (Collider2D enemy2 in hitEnemies2)
        {
            enemy2.GetComponent<GunBoi>().Dead();
        }
```

and this in the second enemy script:

```
    public void Dead()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

but whenever I try to attack the second enemy nothing happens. When I try to attack the first enemy it does work and the enemy dies. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: `I named the second function "Dead()" instead of "Death()" since I thought it wouldn't work if they had the same name` this really doesn't matter at all .. the names are mainly for you ;) As long as they are placed in different scopes (in your case different classes) they can have the same name .. later on this becomes compiled machine code without any names ;) just addresses

Comment: Since your code does exactly the same it sounds like you should rather have a common base class or interface instead of two completely independent classes ... how are the objects different? Do they maybe just lack collider components?

Comment: I have checked and they both have rigidbodies and colliders attached to them. By different I meant that they do completely different things. The first enemy is supposed to move and the other one is supposed to stay in one place and shoot at the player. I also wanna mention that I used the brackeys tutorial on 2D melee combat to help with some stuff (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPiVz1k-fEs&t=932s&ab_channel=Brackeys)

Comment: Please make sure to use the correct tags. Your code is in `c#` ... `unityscript` is/was a JavaScript flavor like custom language previously used by Unity and is long deprecated by now

Answer (score 2):

About your problem: your code is in order. Check if the script have been assigned to the enemy prefab.

Now, a recommendation. If you follow it, your problem may be solved.

You said that you created a new script for the new enemy but they both share one same mechanics: the Death() function (and, as long as they are both enemies, i belive they will share a lot of other mechanics like HP, damage, and other traditional stuff).

In this case, i think that the best solution is to the GunBoi's script be inherited from the common enemy's one.

Replicate a function that do exactly the same thing but have a (not very) different name is a bad practice. If you decide to create a third enemy, you will have to create a third function to destroy it, but again, with a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple things could be wrong, but at first sight I would at least verify those two:

1. are the GunBoi on the good layer
2. Do they have the GunBoi component

We lack too much information to help you further than this.

But honestly you should try to refactor this by having both enemy type have a generic enemy component. There is no reason why should would have to do the collision logic twice. You want to have to write as less code as possible. With your approach you will have to do this for each new enemy type which is both problematic and error prone.

Comment: I have made sure that both enemies are on the right layer and that the second enemy has the Gunboi script attached. The reason I decided to do the collision logic twice is because the two enemies are completely different. They both have different scripts and do different things. The first enemy is meant to partol on a platform and the second one is meant to stay in one place and shoot at the player. (and yes i checked, they both have rigidbody components attached to them).

Comment: I also want to mention that I have tried to just add ```public void Death()``` to the second enemy script as well without modifying the attack script and without adding the second attack logic and it just didn't work